# What are batch.created and batch.updated webhook events?

Tags: stripe-payments

In test mode, I receive sometimes those events: `batch.created` and `batch.updated`

## batch.created

```
{
    "id": "evt_1Fbj*****",
    "object": "event",
    "api_version": "2017-08-15",
    "created": 1573029053,
    "data": {
        "object": {
            "id": "batch_1Fbj*****`,
            "object": "batch",
            "completed": null,
            "content_sha256": null,
            "created": 1573029053,
            "error": null,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": [],
            "results": null,
            "started": null,
            "status": "new",
            "upload_url": null
        }
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "pending_webhooks": 2,
    "request": {
        "id": null,
        "idempotency_key": null
    },
    "type": "batch.created"
}
```

## batch.updated

```
{
    "id": "evt_1Fbj*****",
    "object": "event",
    "api_version": "2017-08-15",
    "created": 1573029059,
    "data": {
        "object": {
            "id": "batch_1FbjujF******",
            "object": "batch",
            "completed": null,
            "content_sha256": null,
            "created": 1573029053,
            "error": null,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": [],
            "results": null,
            "started": 1573029059,
            "status": "processing",
            "upload_url": null
        },
        "previous_attributes": {
            "started": null,
            "status": "new"
        }
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "pending_webhooks": 3,
    "request": {
        "id": null,
        "idempotency_key": null
    },
    "type": "batch.updated"
}
```

I was unable to find informations about them into Stripe Documentation. What are their purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are internal events generated by Stripe when you perform a batch operation in the Dashboard. For example if you refund multiple charges or delete multiple customers in one operation.

Those events are not documented and should not be sent to your endpoint which Stripe will fix in the future. You can safely ignore those events.